# Regarding PDF filename as customised in struts1

Tags: internet-explorer, pdf, servlets

To save the pdf with  file name as automated while saving from ,viewing the pdf for now its like doAction.do iam using Struts 1

response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", String.format("inline; " +"filename=\"%s\"", downLoadFile.getName()));

the inline is not working in IE but working perfect in chrome

Comment: does it work if you replace `inline` by `attachment` (I'm aware that's not exactly what you want but maybe can drill down the source of the error)

Comment: yes its working when i replace with attachment

Comment: And what is the problem / what don't you like about using `attachment`? You might also read the [one](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields) or other [wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Disposition) about it, especially the part about the browser support